# WooCommerce add to cart quantity counting double counting

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

When I open some product, or when I go on category of product, and I want to add, for example, 2 products using quantity -> next -> add to cart at product.

Immediately the product is opening with number 3 inside quantity and if I click on plus it counts me double. For example it starts with 1 then 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13 ...

[image]

You can see on that photo just when I open product category inside quantity it shows me number 3 but not number 1 or 0 also I tried disable all plugins and its not working but if I change template to some other then I not have a quantity at product page

Comment: Is it possible that you're using Step Values (from WooCommerce Advanced Product Quantities)?

Comment: No my friend im not use that plugin

Comment: Can we see some snippets of code or a live page?

Comment: Im fix the problem its be somethinks in function.php some code and im update themes and everythinks it's fine now :) thanks anyway